# Cannot get a bootstrap form to work inside a modal

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, ruby-on-rails-4, twitter-bootstrap-3, modal-dialog, bootstrap-modal

I am using bootstrap to have a form appear inside a modal.  Here is the link that launches the modal:

```
<p>  
    <a class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal"><i class="fa fa-user-plus" ></i>Join Our Newsletter</a>
</p>
```

And here is the modal code:

```
<!-- Modal -->
<div id="myModal" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
  <div class="modal-dialog">

    <!-- Modal content-->
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
        <h4 class="modal-title">Modal Header</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">                  
        <form class="new_email_list" id="new_email_list" action="email_lists_path" accept-charset="UTF-8" data-remote="true" method="post">
          <input name="utf8" type="hidden" value="✓">
          <input class="" placeholder="email" required="required" type="text" name="email_list[email]" id="email_list_email">             
        </form>      
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
```

The modal appears with the form inside it, but nothing in the modal is clickable.  Clicking on the input field or the button does nothing.  None of the mouseovers/hovering does anything.  What is going wrong?

Comment: You're example code doesn't demonstrate the problem you're having, please post an example that recreates the issue which may include any additional CSS/JS you've applied. Where you're placing the modal itself may be the issue so you may need to change the page structure or a z-index value.

Comment: There is nothing wrong with that code. The error relies somewhere else, probably in some custom CSS.